# RoboVM: IDEVICE_E_NO_DEVICE

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm, libimobiledevice

I'm trying to test my libGDX app on an iPod but, simply put, it ain't workin'.

It builds for the simulator, and I can also push an Xcode project with the same bundle ID to my device, so I've not really been able to narrow the problem down to anything.

I am using:

- Android Studio 4.0.1
- RoboVM 2.3.10-SNAPSHOT
- Xcode 11.7
- macOS Catalina 10.15.6
- iOS 13.7 (17H35)

I doubt it's particularly helpful, but here is the error in its entirety:

```
[ERROR] Couldn't start application
org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: IDEVICE_E_NO_DEVICE
    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.IDevice.checkResult(IDevice.java:197)
    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.IDevice.(IDevice.java:57)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.IOSTarget.createIOSDevLauncher(IOSTarget.java:201)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.IOSTarget.createLauncher(IOSTarget.java:175)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.AbstractTarget.doLaunch(AbstractTarget.java:802)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.IOSTarget.doLaunch(IOSTarget.java:784)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.AbstractTarget.launch(AbstractTarget.java:798)
    at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler.launchAsync(AppCompiler.java:1024)
    at org.robovm.idea.running.RoboVmRunProfileState.executeRun(RoboVmRunProfileState.java:72)
    at org.robovm.idea.running.RoboVmRunProfileState.startProcess(RoboVmRunProfileState.java:118)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.CommandLineState.execute(CommandLineState.java:61)
    at org.robovm.idea.running.RoboVmRunner.doExecute(RoboVmRunner.java:79)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner$execute$$inlined$runProfileStarter$1.executeAsync(GenericProgramRunner.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunnerKt$startRunProfile$$inlined$runProfileStarter$1.executeAsync(GenericProgramRunner.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerKtImpl$startRunProfile$startRunnable$1.run(ExecutionManagerKtImpl.kt:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$pollQueueLater$0(TransactionGuardImpl.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: This error happens when usbmuxd isn't running. Source: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/blob/ef091902377c00dc0fb2db87e8d79c8afb5e9010/libimobiledevice/src/main/java/org/robovm/libimobiledevice/IDevice.java More on usbmuxd here: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Usbmux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception stack traces I can see that RoboVM detected your device before compilation (as it got your UDID), compiled project and failed during deployment while trying to get device by UDID.

This happens if you device is not connected anymore or connected not over USB. E.g. over wifi.

Probably you should uncheck `Connect via network` for your device (accessable by  Xcode->Windows->Device and Simulator menu) and connect it using USB.

Comment: Ah, very cool. Connecting over USB works. So is it 
just not capable of deploying over the network? This would normally be okay, but I'm using a free trial of software to route its USB connection through the network [due to virtual machine trouble](https://askubuntu.com/q/1269061/564297), so relying on a USB connection isn't feasible long-term.

Comment: @spacerGIF its downstream dependency limitation -- USB only connection. Will look into this in scope of next release. Sorry no quick fix today.